# Install Laravel 5.2 on Ubuntu Vagrant does not work anymore

Tags: laravel, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5

I've installed Laravel 5.2 about 1 month on a Vagrant VM, on ubuntu.
I created the VM through puphpet. It works perfectly. Laravel was installed easily without any configuration from me.

I tried again a couple days ago to be sure what I did was correct but I got errors...
Errors in the terminal: http://hastebin.com/etugokawun.coffee

Files are installed but when I reach Laravel I have these errors :
`Warning: require(/var/www/teamleague/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/teamleague/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17`

It used to work smoothly and now it's a pain no matter what.
What should I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really include the any code as part of the question, because remote links can become inaccessible over time, or as it turns out in this case [the linked website might be down](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7OzG9.png). And for future readers that might benefit from your question and any answers you get, that will make it impossible to understand the context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In any case, I managed to reinstall it again, changing the PHP version of my VM. So weird.